# Electronic components without rust or corrosion

Tags: voltage, power, transistors, pcb, current

Is there any sort of special conductive material that doesn't rust or cause corrosion?

Answer (score 13):

Gold ...

In applications where this is a requirement you can order gold flash over your copper.  Although in reality there will be some corrosion in very harsh environments.

ENIG ...

Electroless Nickel Immersion Gold is lower cost, Nickel as a barrier, gold to protect the Nickel.

Comment: You're forgetting a few, to start with: Platinum. Depending on environment, also: Titanium, Titanium-Gold, Palladium, Palladium-Gold, even Tellurium-Copper and Phosphor-Bronze could qualify, though it may be unlikely. Specially Palladium-Gold, as in ENEPIG (or was it ENPIG?) for harsher environments and wire-bonding schemes.

Comment: Hey buddy ! start your own answer ! (and I'll up vote it) ;)

Comment: Noh. Cost you votes. :-P

Comment: @Asmyldof bah. Do it. :)

Comment: @hobbs Too late. Also too lazy now. #Wine

Answer (score 5):

There are also non-metallic conductors, including (solid) graphite and conductive polymers, (liquid) solutions of salts, and all (gas) plasmas. The liquids and gases probably don't qualify as part of the answer. Semi-conductors such as those based on silicon and germanium may qualify although they may be more susceptible to corrosion.

Note that thermal and electrical conductivity often go together. For instance, the sea of electrons causes most metals to act both as electrical and thermal conductors. However, some non-metallic materials are practical electrical conductors without being good thermal conductors.

Ref: [“Conductors.” Boundless Chemistry. Boundless, 26 May. 2016](http://www.boundless.com/chemistry/textbooks/boundless-chemistry-textbook/metals-20/band-theory-of-electrical-conductivity-143/conductors-561-3598/).